# Borderlands 2 - Jenkins Challenge

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is Jimmy Jenkins?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84851/where-is-jimmy-jenkins)

Can someone help me out with all misc challenges? I'm having trouble particularly with the Jenkins achievement.

Comment: Your question is too vague. I've renamed it to be about Jenkins only. If you have any other particularo problems, please mention them or post another question.

Comment: I've added another related answer - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95375/shotgun-and-launcher-undiscovered-challenges/95376

Comment: We sorta changed his question on him; should we really be duping it when we've changed the intent of the question?

Comment: Ow, indeed, pretty much a duplicate. Answers over there are a bit worse for an achievement hunter, but diverse... I dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to farm Jimmy Jenkins, if you are on a certain mission.

1. You need to be on an optional mission **Doctor's Orders** from Tannis. Go to Wildlife Exploitation Preserve.
2. Ideally, you need to have **Creature Slaughter Dome** yourself, or farm with someone who has. If you do, run through the preserve up to the Dome, enter and exit it. If you don't have it, you'll have to run through the level from the start each time.
3. Pick all ECHOs on a mission until the one inside the Hyperion complex after the ruined dome. That ECHO will be in one of four (five?) **crates** in a certain room, and each crate will spawn a Midget Loader - one of several varieties, including (rarely) Jimmy Jenkins.
4. If Jenkins does not spawn, make sure you do **not** pick the ECHO itself from a crate (I think you are allowed to open that crate, though). Reload and repeat.

I've read this guide myself recently, and can't find a source now :-( I guess if you're past this mission, you'll have to wait till TVHM, and if you're past that in TVHM, farm with another character. Remember, challenge is awarded to the player who deals the killing blow.

Jenkins also spawns normally in certain containers (ammo crates, lockers and I forgot the third) in only a few areas - again, I only remember Opportunity, and people seem to recommend it. But the chance to find Jimmy "normally" is very low, so do that only if you have no friends and have already completed TVHM :-)

Comment: `I've read this guide myself recently, and can't find a source now` this from the jimmy jenkins page on the borderlands 2 wiki

Comment: Ah, indeed - http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Jimmy_Jenkins - though I've read it elsewhere, in a nice and long forum post.